# Cannot ProxyPass to geoserver if source name is anything other than /geoserver

Tags: geoserver, proxy, apache, tomcat

I have been using apache's `ProxyPass` command to proxy

```
 http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
```

as follows:

```
    ProxyPass /geoserver http://localhost:8082/geoserver
    ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://localhost:8082/geoserver
```

This works fine until I change the source path to

```
    ProxyPass /geoserver1 http://localhost:8082/geoserver
    ProxyPassReverse /geoserver1 http://localhost:8082/geoserver
```

When changed to above, If I go to

```
    http://localhost/geoserver1
```

in a browser, it will be redirected to

```
 http://localhost/geoserver
```

automatically, without the port number. And then this gives an error of 404, address not found.

This happens if the source is anything other than `/geoserver` and the destination is

```
http://localhost:8082/geoserver
```

(I suspect this has something to do with the automatic redirect from

```
http://localhost:8082/geoserver
```

to

```
http://localhost:8082/geoserver/web
```

But I am not sure whether this is the case.

How do I fix it?

This is with GeoServer 2.5 in osgeo live 8

Comment: I see I have the same issue but it's not restricted to GeoServer, It appears to be Tomcat related.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is to do with the Tomcat settings and not with any settings of GeoServer.

Note the [Tomcat docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html) tell us:

> It should be noted that it is not recommended to use a reverse proxy to change the context path because of the multiple issues it creates.

So if you want to run GeoServer under a different name you might consider changing the name of the GeoServer war file deployed, or changing the name in a context file, but if you really want to use the proxy settings the following worked for me:

In **httpd.conf**

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy /gs/>
    Require all granted
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /gs/ ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/geoserv/
ProxyPassReverse /gs/ ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/geoserv/
```

In **server.xml**

```
<Context 
    path="/geoserv"
    docBase="C:\apps\geoserver\gs_2.9x"
    crossContext="true" 
    reloadable="false"
    <!-- having useRelativeRedirects set as true is the important bit! -->
    useRelativeRedirects="true"
/>
```

Comment: In my case, I'm not trying to change the name of the context, but to avoid having to specify it (`http://geoserver.domain/` should be proxying to `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/`). I suspect that the problem is still the `useRelativeRedirects` setting.